# What are CoreDataGeneratedAccessors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I created a CoreData object with a one-to-many relationships, I get some methods `(CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)`. Do we need to implement these methods?
The methods generated automatically are given below :

```
- (void)addCirqitsObject:(Cirqit *)value;
- (void)removeCirqitsObject:(Cirqit *)value;
- (void)addCirqits:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeCirqits:(NSSet *)value;
```

Comment: No, you don't need to implement them.  They will be parsed by CoreData itself and handled appropriately.  Just make sure you don't touch them (even simple changes like removing the "s" from Cirquits will break them).

Comment: in some projects i have seen that, they are made some implementations. what will be the reason?

Comment: The accessors for ordered sets don't (or didn't, I haven't kept up) work, so projects override them. Discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not have to implement those methods, but you can. In the case you don't, CoreData will generate them dynamically for you.

If you want override the default implementation please read the [Core Data Programming Guide (Custom To-Many Relationship Accessor Methods)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html) to find a sample implementation.

A reason to override might be to trigger additional calculations or updates before or after new `Cirqit` objects being added or removed. **But be aware of not to change** the sample implementation code, just add your custom code - otherwise you might break your relationships handling.

Comment: Could you answer "What are CoreDataGeneratedAccessors?" Right now the answer just describes about whether to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the core data generated accessors. You have to pay attention to a few special things like calling willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey, but other than that overriding the accessors is pretty much the same as always.

Courtesy:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/9659750/1865424

I think these links can help you..

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html